# MySQL script does not stop, reboots mysql

Tags: 13.10, mysql, netbeans

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 desktop x64 on my laptop. After the installation I installed MySQL Server `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`

Installation wass successful but I noticed the following issues with MySQL. Using `sudo service mysql start` and `sudo service mysql stop` the database starts and stops correctly. But when I use `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` the database service stops and than it gets spawn again automatically without any user input. Using `ps -A | grep mysql` I noticed that the spawn gets a new PID.

Have you noticed this issue with mysql. For the same reason `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` does the same thing as `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

I need to use `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` command as I would like to integrate MySQL with Netbeans 7.4

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Not at all a solution but using `sudo service mysql stop` is actually the correct way to stop the service. Why not use that?

Comment: I know its the proper way to start and stop a service. But I need to integrate MySQL with Netbeans 7.4. It gives you the option to start and stop the database within the IDE and I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/etc/init/mysql.conf` and comment out the respawn lines:

```
# respawn
# respawn limit 2 5
```